How can I open two web socket questions in Python on a local flask server?
Basically just the title, very poor understanding of web sockets. How can I open two websockets in my Python program?
I'm not sure if I should use multiple web socket imports. I attempted to use flask-sock and websockets separately, but I'm not understanding.

What kind of answer do you expect exactly? Have you tried anything? There's lots of tutorials and examples online, have you tried any of them? What can't you get to work?

I attempted to use ... Show us what you tried.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You would open two websockets the same way you open one... just do it twice.  I don't understand the question.
